# Why does the 555 timer have a maximum frequency of 2MHz?

Tags: frequency, timer, 555

According to [this website,](http://groups.ist.utl.pt/lee/SUBA/Suba_files/555/555ncsu.htm) the 555 timer has a maximum frequency of 2MHz. Why is it not less or more? What property of the timer makes the limit of the frequency?

Comment: Not a single property. What does your car not go faster than x km/h? Is it the design of your motor pistons? Or is it the aerodynamics? Or is it the maximum throughout of the carburetor? Or is it the weight of the car? The friction in the bearings? The resistance of your tires? It's all factors combined.

Comment: The most straightforward one for CMOS 555 timers is the maximum rise/fall times of 75ns/60ns, being approximately 1/10th the 500ns period associated with 2MHz. Under those conditions ~1/5th of your output pulse is rise, ~1/5th is fall, and only 3/5ths is the high level.

Comment: Only newish 555 timers can do 2MHz.  The fanciest ones can get over 3 MHz.  Older ones can't even manage 1MHz.

Comment: [This one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf?ts=1617614265991&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) can do 3 MHz. Next year one may come out that can do 5 MHz.

Comment: @Andyaka available in BGA haha

Comment: Don't be facetious LOL @DKNguyen

Comment: @andyaka I don't think they have a 555, but are you aware of the 74xx series in the GHz range by potato semi? It's always bit of fun to go through these http://www.potatosemi.com/ (also, best IC company name ever)

Comment: Oooh lala!  Le 555 especial!  The BGA thing does seem funny to me too.  I think of the 555 as mostly being a chip for novices like me who would have a lot of extra trouble with a BGA design, but I guess it shows there are still options for the 555 even when bleeding edge processes are available.  I can't believe you can do an 8 lead 555 in a 1.5x1.5mm package!

Comment: @kh maybe it's aimed at manufacturers shrinking their least-cost devices? (E.g. an ON-only IR remote to some cheap device that used to generate 38 kHz wave with a 555, but cost pressure means you needed to get rid of the large plastic case needed for dip or soic 555). Maybe it's aimed at aerospace with people who havecertified designs that they need to rescue from the 1970s? There's money in the poor saps in aerospace/defense who need to avoid competes re-certification at high cost.

Comment: Because it was designed in the 1960s using genuine 1960s transistors.

Answer (score 5):

There's no single answer to your question. It's a mix of the maximum speed of the transistors involved, limits put by maximum currents you want to carry on an IC, the parasitics you can't wish away in the olden packages that 555s are often sold in, the fact that for higher speeds, you'll need smaller capacitors, which means they are less large compared to inherent capacitors.

Also, the fact that if you're building something very fast, you probably won't be happy with what the 555 can do, anyway, so there's little demand backed by actual money that would justify spending millions on devising a higher-speed 555, doing the analog design, taping out that chip, and finally manufacturing it. Where there is no real demand, no products emerge.

In short: the 555 idea is limited by many things, and what it is in your specific use case will depend. If you need higher frequencies than 2 MHz, my bet is that you should be asking a different question, namely how to achieve what you want to achieve through the 555, without t trying to use a 555.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can get 6 MHz.
Sing wave of the 555 timer I haven't found a way to go past it with just the ne555 I haven't tried the others.
I mean you can get 11 MHz but it's definitely not a clear wave

Comment: A "sing wave"? Now I'd like to hear that!

Comment: Yep I mean I got it up to the 11 megahertz but I haven't got a clear wave yet

Comment: Check the videos

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/HTsgJPOED0I?si=eRHMnta85dlcGMAL

Comment: I'm on the boat for 6 MHz this one is 7.52 MHz

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/HTsgJPOED0I?si=yX7ymPrvM8yJHMAC